# TVOS , detect indexPath FocusUpdate

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos, apple-tv

How can i get and detect the indexPath of Item Focused in collectionView with this code or ?

```
- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [didUpdateFocusInContect - UICollectionViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:)

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
     // indexPath that is going to be focused
     print(context.nextFocusedIndexPath)

     // indexPath that is going to lose focus
     print(context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath)
}
```